# JSON - Returning JSON to a input jqGrid autocomplete

Tags: json, jqgrid, autocomplete

I need help in this thing: I'm doing a autocomplete in a jqGrid, and what I need to do is to return JSON to the input of autocomplete. I'm doing something like this, but in my autocomplete just return one value and in the database I have more than one. Somebody could help me in this. I'm doing the return like this:

```
...
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$i=0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
   $response->input['value']=$row[ac_fin_g];
   $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
...
```

But for example.. I have in the database the values for ac_fin_g: {house, home, cake}. If I write the letter "O", the correct to appear is "HOUSE" and "HOME" in my autocomplete, but this is not happening. When I change the code above for this code (for the input="HO"):

```
...
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$i=0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
   $response->input[$i]['value']=$row[ac_fin_g];
   $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
...
```

I have the correct JSON:

```
{"input":[{"value":"HOME      "},{"value":"HOUSE     "}]}
```

I'm sorry but I don't know how to fix this. Somebody could help me?

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Oleg I figured out how to do this. For my case is:

```
$i=0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
$response[] = $row[ac_fin_g]; $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

:)

PS: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830264/how-can-i-convert-the-result-of-this-postgres-db-query-into-json-to-return-to-my) can be useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server should create JSON data which expect jQuery UI. Corresponds to the [jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) the JSON data should be

```
["HOME", "HOUSE"]
```

or

```
[{"label": "Home", "value": "HOME"}, {"label": "House", "value": "HOUSE"}]
```

instead of

```
{"input":[{"value":"HOME      "},{"value":"HOUSE     "}]}
```

which you currently generate. There are way to decode any other JSON data on the client side, but it's better just to follow jQuery UI Autocomplete standard format.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Oleg. And I'm sorry again, but how can I change this? I tried of so many forms. The form that seems like your is: `$i=0; while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { $response = $row[ac_fin_g]; $i++; } echo json_encode($response);`. This returns **"HOME"** when I write **HO** so it's not working yet :(

Comment: I got this! Thanks!!!
If anyone don't know how to do this... in this case is: `$i=0; while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { $response[] = $row[ac_fin_g]; $i++; } echo json_encode($response);` In this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830264/how-can-i-convert-the-result-of-this-postgres-db-query-into-json-to-return-to-my) there is another example :) Thanks for the help people! :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are overwriting one value with another. Just replace this:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
   $response->input['value']=$row[ac_fin_g];
   $i++;
}
```

by

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
   $response->input['value'][]=$row[ac_fin_g];
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit for me... because this returns me something like this: `{"input":{"value":["HOME    ","HOUSE "]}}`, for example, and like @Oleg said, I need something like: `[{"label": "Home", "value": "HOME"}, {"label": "House", "value": "HOUSE"}]`. But thanks for reply :)